# gforth : using the return stack

Tags: forth, gforth

I am in the process of learning *GForth*.

Now trying to understand and get some practice using the *return stack*.

Can somebody with more experience tell me what I am missing ?

Here is the issue.

If use these definitions, it all works as I expect :

```
: syr dup 2 mod 0 = if 2 / else 3 * 1 + endif ;

: collatz begin dup 1 <> while dup . syr repeat . ;
```

These area a few tests:

```
1 collatz 1  ok
2 collatz 2 1  ok
3 collatz 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1  ok
4 collatz 4 2 1  ok
```

Now comes the question. Changing the previous code I want to make use of the *return stack*. Using these definitions:

```
: syr dup 2 mod 0 = if 2 / else 3 * 1 + endif >r ;

: collatz { ini } ini begin dup 1 <> while dup . syr r> repeat . ;
```

I also expect things to work, but it doesn't.

This is a sample test:

```
2 collatz 2
:424: Invalid memory address
2 >>>collatz<<<
Backtrace:
$7FC88491B470 ;s
$7FC88491B500 syr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returns stack in Forth can be only used to temporary store data within a definition. It **cannot** be used to pass data across definition boundaries.

See the section [3.2.3.3 Return stack](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:returnstack) of Forth-2012 (the standard):

- All values placed on the return stack within a definition shall be removed before the definition is terminated or before `EXIT` is executed.

Your second definition for `syr` violates this restriction in the fragment  `>r ;`.

If you need an additional stack, you can just implement it or load an existing implementation, and use it at your own discretion (for example, see a library [zstack.f](https://github.com/rufig/spf4-utf8/blob/master/devel/%7Epinka/samples/2004/test/zstack/zstack.f)).

And, please, include [stack diagrams](https://forth-standard.org/standard/notation#subsection.2.2.2) in your definitions, especially when you share your code.

Comment: OK, thank you for this reply. It sheds light on a few aspects of the Forth language I was not yet aware of.

But at the same time it brings doubts on what is expeted below.

Comment: This is what I was doing before writing the question in this post. I was reading this tutorial:

https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Return-Stack-Tutorial.html#Return-Stack-Tutorial

And one can read at the bottom of the page:

"Assignment: Can you rewrite any of the definitions you wrote until now in a better way using the return stack?"

Now that I have an answer to my post I somewhat wonder what was expected in this assignment. Can you guess what is expected ?

Comment: @Michel, your definitions `syr` and `collatz` don't involve stack juggling, and so they cannot be rewritten in a better way using the return stack.  The mentioned assignment just assumes that if have already written fairly complex definitions, the use of the return stack could make them simpler.

Comment: I see. In that case it's OK. I will just not know for the time being what such a complex case would be.

Comment: Just for learning purposes, try implementing the word `fibsum ( u -- u.sum )`, which returns the sum of the first _u_ numbers from the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: I have actually followed your suggestion of implementing fibsum ( u -- u.sum ).
I even implemented a few versions. But I was thinking this would give me an opportunity to make some good use of the return stack. Unfortunately when I tried I was only able to produce a few crashes. So fibsum must not be a good use case for the return stack, or I do not yet understand how to properly use it (in practice).

Comment: Let's discuss this separately, for the greater benefit of the community. Just post a new question on how to implement `fibsum` in Forth in different ways.

Comment: Why not but this only makes sense if you tell me that there exits a way to implement fibsum using the return stack. Which I do not know at this point.

Comment: Of course, it exists. Otherwise, why I suggested it. In addition, it is awkward to paste code and explanations here in a comment on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Michel, try to implement `rot ( x3 x2 x1 -- x2 x1 x3 )`, which just moves the third item to the top. The return stack is just an additional stack that can be used within a definition.

Comment: I followed your advice and made a new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77383795/making-use-of-the-return-stack-in-gforth).