# Making use of the return stack in the fibsum example in Forth

Tags: forth, gforth

While learning `gforth` I have implemented the *Fibonacci* sequence in a few forms.

Below are some implementations of the *fibsum* definition, which sums up all the *Fibonacci* values up to a certain rank.

In other words the *Fibonacci* sequence being:
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89

*fibsum* will produce:
0 1 2 4 7 12 20 33 54 88 ....

Here is my first implementation of *fibsum*

```
variable fbsum
: fibsum ( u -- u.sum ) { p } 0 1 \ Fibonacci-Sum.
\ This sums the first u values of the Fibonacci sequence.
0 fbsum !
p 0= if drop dup else 1 fbsum ! endif
p 1 u+do
 over over +
 dup fbsum +!
 rot drop
loop
2drop fbsum ? ;
```

Here is the second implementation

```
variable fbsum
: fibsum2x ( u -- u.sum ) { p } 0 1 \ Fibonacci recursive (1)
p dup 1 > if
  dup 1- recurse swap
  2 - recurse +
  nip nip
else
  p 1 = if 1 fbsum +! endif \ Here p matches the argument to the top call!
  nip nip
endif ;
: fibsum2 ( u -- u.sum ) \ Fibonacci-Sum.
\ This sums the first u values of the Fibonacci sequence.
{ m }
0 fbsum !
m 1+ 1 u+do
  i fibsum2x drop
loop
fbsum ? ;
```

And this is the third implementation

```
variable fbsum
: fibsum3x ( u -- u.sum ) { p } 0 1 \ Fibonacci recursive (2)
p dup 1 > if
  dup 1- recurse swap
  2 - recurse +
  nip nip
else
  \ p 1 = if 1 fbsum +! endif \ Here p matches the argument to the top call!
  nip nip
endif ;
: fibsum3 ( u -- u.sum ) \ Fibonacci-Sum.
\ This sums the first u values of the Fibonacci sequence.
{ m }
0 fbsum !
m 1+ 1 u+do
  i fibsum3x
  fbsum +!
loop
fbsum ? ;
```

As one can see I am not making use of the return stack in my code.
In fact I tried but failed. So here comes my question.

How can I modify the code above and make a correct use of the return stack ?

Comment: To make you definitions match their stack diagrams, you have to use `@` instead of `?` at the end of the definition.

Comment: Just to make sure I correctly understand this comment. You mean the stack diagram should be "( u -- u.sum )" as it is and the end of the definition: "fbsum @ ;" as you point out.
Or the stack diagram should be "( u -- )" and the end of the definition: "fbsum ? ;" as it is now. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right — either one or the other.  Because `? ( addr -- )` consumes an address from the stack and does not place anything on the stack, just prints a number from the cell at _addr_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes.

1. Gforth is an implementation for the Forth programming language. Implementations for Forth are also known as Forth systems. It's better to learn Forth in general (using Gforth, or another Forth system) than the Gforth system particularities. For example, use `{: :}` to declare [local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191233/1300170), instead of `{ }`.
2. Usually, if you use variables, whether they are static or local (temporary), you have less need for the return stack to rearrange arguments. Therefore, to demonstrate the use of the return stack, we will eliminate variables.
3. The return stack is just an additional stack available with [known limitations](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:returnstack) for a Forth program. The return stack cannot be used to pass arguments into a definition, or return them from a definition.

---

To correctly pose the problem on the Fibonacci sequence, we should describe it more carefully to show **what indexing** is used. From the recurrence relation:

```
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(n) = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

it's obvious that we start from `0`.

Just for reference, the word `fib` can be *inefficiently* implemented from this recurrence relation like this:

```
: fib ( u.index -- u.value )
  dup 2 u< if exit then
  dup 2 - recurse  swap 1 - recurse  +
;
```

---

So, the sum of the Fibonacci sequence elements up to a certain rank means the sum of elements up to the certain index, starting from `0`. And the recurrence relation for `fibsum()` is following:

```
fibsum(0) = 0
fibsum(n) = fibsum(n-1) + fib(n)
```

Let's define the test cases for the word `fibsum` from the very beginning:

```
t{ 0 fibsum ->  0 }t
t{ 1 fibsum ->  1 }t
t{ 2 fibsum ->  2 }t
t{ 3 fibsum ->  4 }t
t{ 4 fibsum ->  7 }t
t{ 6 fibsum -> 20 }t
```

In the Gforth distribution, the words `t{ -> }t` are defined in [test/ttester.fs](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/test/ttester.fs), include this file to run the above tests.

From the recurrence relation for `fibsum()` we can get the following recursive implementation for the word `fibsum`:

```
: fibsum ( u.index -- u.sum )
  dup 0= if exit then
  dup 1- recurse swap fib +
;
```

And an iterative implementation is even shorter (but slightly more complicated):

```
: fibsum ( u.index -- u.sum )
  0 swap 1+ 0 do  i fib +  loop
;
```

These implementations are simple, but they perform **a lot of excessive computation**.

An efficient way is to calculate both the value and the sum on each step.
The idea is that we define the word `fibsum-next ( u1 u2 u.sum2 -- u2 u3 u.sum3 )`, that calculates the next value and next sum from the previous value and previous sum; actually, to calculate the next value, we should use two previous values: `u3=u1+u2`, `u.sum3=u3+u.sum2`.

The test cases:

```
t{ 0 0 0 fibsum-next  -> 0 0 0 }t
t{ 0 0 1 fibsum-next  -> 0 0 1 }t

t{ 0 1 1 fibsum-next  -> 1 1 2 }t
t{ 1 1 2 fibsum-next  -> 1 2 4 }t
t{ 1 2 4 fibsum-next  -> 2 3 7 }t
```

NB: this word returns the correct values *recurrently* starting from the index 2 only, i.e., staring from the input `( 0 1 1 )`.

An implementation without using the return stack:

```
: fibsum-next ( u1 u2 u.sum2 -- u2 u3 u.sum3 )
  -rot tuck + rot over +
;
```

And the variant with using the return stack (finally!):

```
: fibsum-next ( u1 u2 u.sum2 -- u2 u3 u.sum3 )
  >r tuck + dup r> +
;
```

In this case the use of the return stack does not make code shorter, but can be easier to implement, and more efficient.

As a beginner, you'll probably want to write more stack diagrams, like this:

```
: fibsum-next ( u1 u2 u.sum2 -- u2 u3 u.sum3 )
  >r    ( u1 u2 ) ( R: u.sum2 )
  tuck  ( u2 u1 u2 )
  +     ( u2 u3 )
  dup   ( u2 u3 u3 )
  r>    ( u2 u3 u3 u.sum2 ) ( R: )
  +     ( u2 u3 u.sum3 )
;
```

In the implementation for `fibsum` we should correctly prepare the initial arguments for `fibsum-next` and run the loop:

```
: fibsum ( u.index -- u.sum )
  dup 2 u< if exit then
  1- >r  0 1 1  r>  0 do fibsum-next loop  nip nip
;
```

In this case, it's difficult to rearrange the arguments without an additional stack or variables. And we just used the return stack.

Well, we can use the [word `roll`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/ROLL), but it's usually very inefficient.

Comment: I am using some time to take a close look at your forth code. I notice that the gforth I am using (gforth 0.7.3) does not use "2-" like you do. I need to change it to "2 -" (with a space). "1-" works though.

Comment: @Michel, thank you, I have updated the code in the post.

Comment: You write "... defined in test/ttester.fs, include this file ...".
How do you do that? I downloaded the file locally and tried:
"require ttester.fs" and "include ttester.fs". Both lead to nothing good.

Comment: I did a dowload using: "wget https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/test/ttester.fs", without being sure that was the right thing to do.

Comment: Gforth 0.7.3 is quite old. If `ttester.fs` does not work for you, just ignore the test cases, and do testing manually/interactively, as before.

Comment: Unless I am not using it (ttester.fs) as I should.

Comment: Gforth v0.7.3 contains `test/ttester.fs`, it can be included from the installation directory. OTOH, by your `wget` command you download data to render html web-page. It doesn't work. You have to use the button **Raw** at the top-right part of the web-page section to obtain URL to the file itself. The right command is: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/forthy42/gforth/master/test/ttester.fs`

Comment: I read all your code and explanations. I owe you a big "Thank You !", for the detailed explanations and comments. I do not know what you usually do in life, but you would obviously be an excellent programming teacher.